# GZIP NSData iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, gzip, nsdata

Hi guys I'm trying to zip an NSData which is a text file with multiple lines using https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP. Everything works fine except that when I gunzip the file on another device I get strange characters at the beginning of each line of the resulting txt file, something like this `¤¤AccelerometerEvent,1.0,1.0,1.0,143957782`.

The code is very simple:

```
NSData *compressedData = [dataToZip gzippedDataWithCompressionLevel:1.0];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[compressedData writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gz", [self getLogArchiveFileName]]] atomically:YES];
```

previously I was using another approach to generate a compressed file with zlib but then I have problem at the server side to unzip it, then I decided to go for GZIP. It is not a communication problem that corrupts the file because it occurs both if I send the files to the server and if I copy them to my computer with Xcode. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: How are you creating `dataToZip`?

Answer (score 0):

My first suspect would be a BOM characters.

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence
>   0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. A text editor or web browser misinterpreting the text
>   as ISO-8859-1 or CP1252 will display the characters ï»¿ for this.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Fire up a hex editor and see what bytes the text file start with to verify.